# Generate JWT in WSO2 by authenticating user via a different server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can use WSO2 (5.11) IS to generate JWT with information stored on server that is not WSO2 that is used for autnetication? My use case is to login user via WSO2 IS, but the actual authentication will happen on a different server, not WSO2. In turn this server upon authenticating the user, will call WSO2 to generate JWT with custom data that it sends. If I understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623445/wso2-is-custom-authenticator) correctly, I need to create local authenticator, is this the approach I should take in my use case?

Moreover, if this approach is possible, will I be able to use WSO2 SSO to allow user to access applications on remote server, or is WSO2 SSO strictly for applications running on WSO2 server itself?

Comment: What do you refer to as a "remote server". Is it for an external userstore or a federated identity provider?

Comment: I changed remote to different as remote was a bit confusing. This is for external userstore - a database with user credentials as well as roles, groups that this user belongs.

Comment: @positron Based on your last reply we understood that you need to connect an external userstore with WSO2 IS 5.11.0. This feature is already built-in in WSO2 IS and please refer [1] to get more details about how to connect the userstores with WSO2 IS.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/configuring-user-stores/

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka I need to connect to external store using REST API and I thought this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626583/409225, was about that, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to connect to some external store using REST API, you can write some custom local authenticators and deploy into Identity servicer. You can implement the custom local authenticator to call your store using some REST API and authenticate the user.

[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/writing-a-custom-local-authenticator/
[2]https://github.com/vihanga-liyanage/samples-is-1/tree/master/custom-local-authenticator
[3]https://everything1know.wordpress.com/2019/09/17/wso2-is-custom-local-authenticator/