# Calling local authenticator from REST call

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In examples cited in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695123/generate-jwt-in-wso2-by-authenticating-user-via-a-different-server/65882670#65882670) the flow is through an app that authenticates and issues access token. What I am trying to do now is to get token via https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token endpoint and be able to execute local authenticator (LA) during authentication process. However, upon executing of the endpoint I don't see my LA being called. I see it being active in OSGi console. Does local authenticator works only with a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use the custom local authenticators to authenticate the rest API, but you can achieve the same by writing a custom grant type[1]. You can pass the attributes to verify against the users as parameters

[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/#writing-a-custom-oauth-20-grant-type